# Writing product and remainder

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given some positive integers, an operation is to choose two integers $a\geq b$, delete them, and write $ab$ and $a\pmod b$ instead. Must the number $0$ eventually appear?

For example, when there are two numbers, the number $0$ must eventually appear. This is because one number keeps increasing and the other number decreasing. When there are more than two numbers, maybe a similar idea works (i.e. the numbers must keep getting "farther apart"), but I'm not sure how to formalize it.

Comment: I understand that the input is a $n$-tuple $[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]$. If $n=2$ the output is $[ab, a\% b]$ (where $a\%b$ is the remainder of the division $a/b$). What is the output if $n>2$?

Comment: For $n>2$ we just choose two numbers arbitrarily and do this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ and you choose $a_i$ and $a_j$ with $i<j$, and replace $a_i$ with the modulo and $a_j$ with the product, you may notice that the modulo is less than the minimum of $a_i$ and $a_j$.

So the new tuple is smaller than the initial one via [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Now use that $\mathbb N^n$ is [well ordered](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Finite_Lexicographic_Order_on_Well-Ordered_Sets_is_Well-Ordering) with lexicographical order. So the process cannot infinitely go on, and eventually a zero must appear.

Comment: OP said $a_i$ mod $a_j$ for $a_i>a_j$ only...

Comment: If one is allowed to take smaller mod larger, then one can take 1 and 2 and continue infinitely without getting a zero.